# Semantic Multi Select dropdown values in server side c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, semantic-ui

I'm building a web page using Semantic UI Framework.I'm using a multi select Dropdown component in web page. I'm able to implement the dropdown and select values. But the problem is i want to access the values selected by the user in server side using C#, in code behind all i get is first selected value. How can i get all the values selected by user.

Comment: Perhaps you could populate a `HiddenField` on the front-end when the dropdown changes (using jQuery, as you've tagged), and retrieve the value of that instead of the dropdown on the codebehind.

Comment: Technically i can do that but i have around 30 of multi select dropdown values on the form. I  am looking for a more generic solution. If i go with this route i need to add 30 hidden fields and track them which makes it complex.

Comment: I mean, I wouldn't say you need a HiddenField for each value. If the person selected "Value 1" and "Value 2" in the dropdown, the hiddenfield could just contain "Value 1|Value 2". Split at the pipe and you now have an array of all selected values. Otherwise, not too familiar with Semantic UI so I can't be of much more help.

Comment: Can you post your Html for one of the listmenu

Comment: Thanks your approach wont work as form as 30 multi select controls, i will wait for some one familiar with semantic ui to respond.